# Typescript knex : Cannot read property 'client' of undefined

Tags: typescript, knex.js

my knexfile:

```
import knex from 'knex';
import path from 'path';
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();

interface KnexConfig {
  [key: string]: object;
}

const config: KnexConfig = {
  developement: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      user: process.env.DB_USER,
      password: process.env.DB_PASS,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10,
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'infra', 'knex', 'migrations'),
    },
    timezone: 'UTC',
    useNullAsDefault: true,
  },
};
const KnexInstance = knex(config['development'] as knex.Config);
module.exports = KnexInstance;
```

my directory to migrations is: src/infra/knex/migrations:
my folder structure:

[image]

my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "@types"],
    "paths": {
      "@modules/*": ["modules/*"],
      "@infra/*": ["infra/*"],
      "@config/*": ["config/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src", "__tests__"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

i get this error on yarn knex:

> yarn knex migrate:make add_custom_functions

error:

> Requiring external module ts-node/register (node:10600)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'client' of undefined
> at Object.Knex [as default] (C:\Users\spiriT\ms-emasa\node_modules\knex\lib\knex.js:22:42)

Comment: "developement" != "development"

Answer (score 2):

You have a spelling error in the following line, with the result that `config.development` is undefined. It may be worth using dot accessor syntax instead of square bracket accessors to allow your editor to pick up typos like this.

```
  developement: {
```

Comment: what? i dont undestand i have same developement: {} can u more specific?

Comment: Look very closely at the spelling of the word 'development'.